# setInterval calling two async functions conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues with two async functions. They are designed to sequentially get a login link from an API  but sometimes the web service is not ready, because it's dependent on a physical device (which can be reset) and sometimes initial render occurs before the service starts.

So the interval runs the two async function every 2 seconds if the `authConfigURL` or `loginURL` are not populated, this can't be optimal, at least not in the current state.

Originally I had a `useEffect()` with both these functions and calling them, passing `loginURL` and `authConfigURL` to the dependency array. I couldn't quite figure out the right way to run the requests at a certain interval if the URLs were not populated.

Is there a better way to handle calling the functions if the condition isn't met or the response of the request is empty?

```
 function useInterval(callback, delay) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      savedCallback.current = callback;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      function tick() {
        savedCallback.current();
      }

      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }, [delay]);
  }


  useInterval(() => {
    if (!authConfigURL || !loginURL) {
      setIsWaiting(true);
      fetchRootResources();
      fetchAuthenticationConfig();
    }
  }, 2000);

  async function fetchRootResources() {
    const rootURL = "/admin/api/rest/";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(rootURL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Accept: "blah"},
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error("Handle response codes", response);
        setErrorMessage("Error fetching Root REST API Resources");
      }
      // if the response contains no data this will error out
      const data = await response.json();
      // set rootResources here
      setRootResources({
        time: data.links.time,
        // 10 or so other links
      });
      // this URL is needed in the next async function
      setAuthConfigURL(data.links.auth_config);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching root resources", error);
    }
  }

  async function fetchAuthenticationConfig() {
    // authConfigURL seems to be empty on initial render
    console.log("fetching authConfig with url: ", authConfigURL);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(authConfigURL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Accept: "blah" },
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error("Handle response codes", response);
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setLoginURL(data.data.links.login);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching auth config", error.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why is `fetchAuthenticationConfig` being called without waiting for `fetchRootResources` to complete? This would result in `fetchAuthenticationConfig` always using the `authConfigURL` obtained in the previous interval. It sounds like retrying failed requests if they time out after 2 (or more) seconds)  may be better than hammering the API until you get two that succeed.

Comment: So remove `fetchAuthenticationConfig()` from the interval and call it from inside `fetchRootResources()` is the `response.status === 200`?

Comment: Possibly or `fetchRootResources().then(fetchAuthenticationConfig).catch( ... handle errors or retry ...)`. Recall that `async` functions return a promise. IMHO using an interval timer at all may not be a good choice.

Comment: Do you mind answering with an example using `.then()` ?

Comment: I ended up putting `fetch` calls in the same function for convenience. However I did use a `.then` clause to separate processing data from fetching it. See my answer the example.

Answer (score 0):

This post looks at an alternative approach to retry failed attempts to obtain "root" and "authorization" data from a server before allowing the user to login.

- In concept two server requests are attempted in succession and if either request times out, fails or returns bad data, the requests are retried from the beginning. Retry logic supports setting the maximum number of retries and the time between retries without using an interval timer.
- Broader issues of the best way to handle server outages or the practical benefits of retrying failed operations within a short time period have deliberately not been looked at.
- Various techniques and coding styles could be used to provide error handling in this situation. To improve working code or discuss the merits of individual approaches please consider posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for feedback.
- *Updated*: include timeout for fetch response from server (coded as `Promise.race([ fetch-request, expiry-timer])` to match behavior of the interval timer.

An example in response to comment:

```js
"use strict";

const getRootResources = rootURL =>  fetch(rootURL, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Accept: "blah"}
});
const getAuthConfig = authConfigURL => fetch(authConfigURL, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Accept: "blah" }
});
const ResponseError = new Error("Fetch response timeout");
const RootError = new Error("Error fetching Root REST API Resources");
const AuthError =  new Error("Failed to obtain config data from server");
const RetryError = new Error("An error occurred connecting to server, please retry again later");

const setupLogin = async () => {
  const rootURL = "https://www.example.com/admin/api/rest/";
  const maxRetry = 3;
  const retryMsec = 2000;
  const delay = async msec=> new Promise( resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, msec));
  const responseMsec = 2000;
  const expire = (msec,reason)=> new Promise((resolve,reject)=> setTimeout(reject, msec, reason));

  let rootData;
  let authData;

  for( var tryAgain = maxRetry; tryAgain; --tryAgain) {
    console.log("tries remaining: %s", tryAgain);
    let response = null;
    rootData = null;
    authData = null;
    try {
      response = await Promise.race( [
        getRootResources( rootURL),
        expire(responseMsec, ResponseError)
      ]);
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error("Handle response codes", response);
        throw RootError;
      }
      rootData = await response.json(); // may throw

      const authConfigURL = rootData.links.auth_config;
      response = await Promise.race( [
        getAuthConfigURL( authConfigURL),
        expire(responseMsec, ResponseError)
      ]);
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error("Handle response codes (config)", response);
        throw AuthError;
      }
      authData = await response.json();
      break;
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.error("Fetch or getting json failed");
      console.log(err);
      await delay(retryMsec);
      continue;
    }
  }
  if( tryAgain <= 0) {
    throw RetryError;
  }
  return {rootData, authData};
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    setupLogin()
    .then( ({rootData, authData}) => {
      console.log("setupLogin() succeeded");
      // enable page login features:
      // setRootResources( rootData); // or as needed
      // setAuthConfig( authData);    // or as needed
      // ... blah
    })
    .catch( err=> {
       console.log("setupLogin() failed");
        console.error(err);
        // disable page login features and notify user
    });
});
```

```html
Run to test that code compiles and reports failures to reach server.
```

Note that `setupLogin` returns a promise for `{rootData, authData}` and leaves processing them to later in the promise chain.